# Find words in a string that do not start with * without using negative lookbehind

Tags: regex

I'm looking to find all FOOs in a string that do not begin with *. For example in

```
*FOO FOO FOO*
```

FOO and FOO$ should match but not *FOO.  The kicker is that I can't use negative lookbehinds `(?<!\*)`.  Is there a way to do this without negative lookbehinds?

Answer (score 2):

If it's only matching you're after, maybe you could do it with

```
([^$]|^)FOO
```

It tests for a character other than `$`, *or* start of line, followed by `FOO`.

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tS2wD1/1).

Comment: That seems to also include spaces or other characters in front of FOO as part of the match.  `AFOO` should not match.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "If it's only matching you're after..." because it matches correctly, but if you're after some kind of extraction, it won't work. What language are you using?